# Gmail listview flip animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-5.0-lollipop

I was trying to create an animation just like that we see in Gmail's listview widget. When we select the row, we press the circle on the left and it flips into a checked mark.

What I was planning to do was to create an animation set, with two scale animations. For some strange reason it doesn't work.

I am using a single image for the time being and applying the flip onto that. This is my anim.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
    <scale
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="0.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        >
    </scale>
    <scale
        android:startOffset="2000"
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromXScale="0.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:toXScale="1.0"
        android:toYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        >
    </scale>
</set>
```

The animation is easy to read. I am starting a scale from 100 to 0. then scaling it back to 100. When I apply this on the imageview, I don't see any animation at all.

This is how I load the animation:

```
final AnimationSet animationSet = (AnimationSet) AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.flip);
mCompanyProfileImage.startAnimation(animationSet);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are lucky!! because I've just developed a new library [FlipView](https://github.com/davideas/FlipView) that includes basic flip animation and extends `ViewFlipper`. I mean a fully customizable library where you will be able to swap any kind of views and layouts with any kind of animation and shapes you desire (and much more), included the Gmail image flipping that you search.

Please have a look.

Answer (score 2):

This is the exact answer:

1) define two animation xml file in anim folder:

scale_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="150" />
```

scale_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="0.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:fillAfter="false"
    android:duration="150" />
```

2) in your Activity:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourActivity.this, R.anim.scale_out);
layoutWithCircleDrawable.startAnimation(animation);
```

and then:

```
animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                //your code for change the layout image or ...

                Animation animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(YourActivity.this, R.anim.scale_in);
                layoutWithCircleDrawable.startAnimation(animation2);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

i could not identify any particular flaw in that program, somehow it dint work for me , if you are interested you can have a look at my other customization ,hope it will help you.
**Javaclass**

```
import android.animation.AnimatorSet;
import android.animation.AnimatorInflater;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.AlphaAnimation;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    AnimatorSet set;
    Button horizontal,vertical;
     ImageView imgView;
     Animation in;
    Boolean check=false;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        horizontal=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        vertical=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
         in = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
        in.setDuration(300);
        horizontal.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                imgView  = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.this, R.animator.animfliphorizontal);
                set.setTarget(imgView);
                set.start();
                anim();
            }


        });
        vertical.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
              imgView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageview);
                set = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(MainActivity.this, R.animator.animflipvertical);
                set.setTarget(imgView);
                set.start();
                anim();
            }
        });
    }

    private void anim() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
if(check==false)
{
    check=true;
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.background2);
}
                else
{
    check=false;
    imgView.setImageResource(R.drawable.background);
}
                imgView.setAnimation(in);

            }
        }, 500);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

below u can see an xml file and 2 diffrent object animaters for horizontal and vertical ,check it out

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HORIZONTAL"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="VERTICAL"
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageview" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="FLIP MODE"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and the 2 animation folders for them

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--animfliphorizontal-->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="rotationX"
        android:valueFrom="180"
        android:valueTo="0" >
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--animflipvertical-->
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:ordering="sequentially" >
    <objectAnimator
        android:duration="1000"
        android:propertyName="rotationY"
        android:valueFrom="0"
        android:valueTo="180" >
    </objectAnimator>
</set>
```